# Top-down algorithm to build a heap recursively

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am a little confused about the top-down requirement in the question I am working on.

This is an algorithmic problem, so I will use pseudocode.
Suppose we have an algorithm to sort an array **A** of length n.
The sorting algorithm has a function **buildMaxHeap** that turns the array into a heap before anything else happens:

```
HeapSrt(A){
  A.buildMaxHeap() // turn array A into a maxheap
  for i = A.length-1 to 0
    swap(A, 0, i)
    A.siftDwn(0)
}
```

where buildMaxHeap is a bottom-up iterative function:

```
A.buildMaxHeap(){
  for i = (n-1)/2 to 0
  A.siftDwn(i)
}
```

Suppose, we need to turn **buildMaxHeap** into a **top-down recursive function**.
We can assume that the leaf lvl is full (every parent element has exactly 2 children).
Also, we can assume that the sift down function is already implemented.

**My question:**

I am somewhat confused about the top-down requirement: I start recursion at the top, but the actual siftdwn galore starts at the bottom (once we reach the base case). So, does it count as a **top-down** recursive heapfying method?

Thank you!

Comment: I see about 4 questions here. Could you limit your question to one question? Multi-questions are usually closed.

Comment: I limited it to 1 question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive algorithm is a top down algorithm.

True, the problem is still solved with the bottom of the heap getting sorted out first, and only then the top of the heap, but this is not in contradiction with a top down approach.

In general, the first "problem" that gets solved with a recursive algorithm, is one that occurs in the leaves of its recursion tree: once you a problem is found that can be solved, it back tracks. And the last problem that is solved, is the initial problem with which that recursive algorithm is started. This is typical for recursive algorithms.

The characteristic of a top down algorithm is that it starts by looking at the top-level, "big" problem, and then decides to *break it down* into one or more "easier" problems, which are then tackled recursively. When those solutions become available the top level problem can be solved also.

An inductive algorithm does not start with the top level problem. It *immediately* addresses an "easy" problem, and solves that first. Then that solution is used to solve a next problem...etc.

It is true that the order in which subproblems are solved may turn out to be the same order for both approaches. But that order is not what defines an algorithm to be top down or bottom up. The key is: which is the problem that the algorithm *addresses* first; not what it *solves* first.

### Heap construction

When speaking of heap *construction*, the terms bottom up and top down are also used in a different way. They then refer to the part of the heap that is constructed first. This can be confusing...

Even though there is a (less efficient) heap construction algorithm that repeatedly increases the size of a heap by adding one element to it with the normal heap_insert algorithm, this is not a true top-down *algorithm*:

```
A.buildMaxHeap():
   for i = 0 to n-1:
       A.heapInsert(a[i], i) # second argument is actual size of the heap before insertion
```

This *does* construct the heap from the top down, but actually it starts with addressing the easiest problem: creating a heap with one value. And once it has that, it solves the next easiest problem, ...etc. And that is actually a characteristic of a bottom up algorithm.